# Datastax Opscenter 5.0: Getting "InvalidGroup.NotFound" when adding node via AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, opscenter

I am getting an "InvalidGroup.NotFound" when trying to add an additional node to my cluster through OpsCenter via AWS. The existing node running OpsCenter is in the VPC and is already using the security group that I'm trying to set on the node I'm trying to add. So my theory is that OpsCenter is sending the name of the security group to the AWS api rather than the security group ID, which is required when in the VPC. If this is the case, I don't suppose there is some kind of work around? Can anyone give me some insight in to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, OpsCenter does not support VPC. This will change in the near future (most likely after the next release in a couple of months).